# Spring data Neo4J does not create all the properties of a node for HAProxy cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, neo4j, tomcat7, spring-data-neo4j, haproxy

We have created a Neo4J cluster which uses HAProxy as a load balancer using the documentation available at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-haproxy.html. 
We are using Spring Data Neo4J graph repositories in our application server to create nodes on the Neo4J   cluster.

We have separated the read and write Neo4J servers and trying to create a node on the Neo4J write server but when the application server sends a request to Neo4J write server it only creates node with only one property and throws following exception.We are sending write requests to Neo4j master and reads are from all instances.

Infrastructure used-
Neo4j instances on E2 servers.
HA proxy for load balancing on top of Neo4j servers.

Neo4j has no public IPs so it can be accessed only through app server.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: error adding labels, received org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RequestResult@31ccc77f
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.addLabels(ExecutingRestAPI.java:303)
    at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.addLabels(RestAPIFacade.java:319)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase.createNode(SpringRestGraphDatabase.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityStateHandler.createNode(EntityStateHandler.java:151)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.EntityStateHandler.useOrCreateState(EntityStateHandler.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.write(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:357)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:351)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.save(AbstractGraphRepository.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:442)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:427)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:381)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide more details about your code, routing setup etc.

And how the routing is affecting the code (request) execution.

Also if you do reads after writes, you have to make sure that these requests are also routed to the server that you wrote to.

You might also want to try SDN 3.3.M1 with the new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase which uses the transactional endpoint to create data over the wire transactionally. Just to see if it works better.